# Replacing text that is not inside DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my work I have come to this problem where, inside a contenteditable, I need to replace text that is not inside DOM element. Just a bare text or text node. I'm getting the textNode with `window.getSelection();` and I need to replace the text.

I really don't want to go with replace or regex to replace that text with an element.

Can someone help?

Sample code here:

```js
$('#editable').click(function($e){
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    if(sel.type === "Caret" && sel.focusNode.data !== undefined && $e.originalEvent.type == "click"){
     let el = (sel.anchorNode.parentElement.childNodes.length < 2 && sel.anchorNode.parentElement !== this) ? sel.anchorNode.parentElement : false;
        if(el) el.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Got you!</span>';
        else alert(sel.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example, click the text to replace:</p>

<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:4px;">You can't get me <strong id="item1">You can get me</strong> You can't get me
<div>You can't get me <strong id="item1">You can get me</strong> You can't get me</div></div>
```

Here is the same sample code in Tryit Editor that replicates the problem, if you fancy that: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKMLYB0T48VC

Comment: "I really don't want to go with _replace_ or regex to replace that text with an element." Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, meaning that I don't wan't to search for similar text from global text. If you don't know the exact text position you need to replace, you can replace a similar text somewhere else. I also just got a good tip for a solution, from my colleague, and I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution now.

I found the parent element with all the child elements that can be targeted for editing from `window.getSelection();` Method to replace the targeted text was to cycle trough all the elements and compare the `prevElement` if text is after some DOM and `nextElement` if before some DOM.

Here is the working sample for those who stuck with the same problem:

```js
$('#editable').click(function($e){
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    if(sel.type === "Caret" && sel.focusNode.data !== undefined && $e.originalEvent.type == "click"){
    console.log(sel)
     let el = (sel.anchorNode.parentElement.childNodes.length < 2 && sel.anchorNode.parentElement !== this) ? sel.anchorNode.parentElement : false;
        if(!el){
        
            let buf = false;
            if(sel.focusNode.nextSibling){
                let cn = sel.focusNode.parentElement.childNodes;
                for(i in cn){
                    if(cn[i] == sel.focusNode.nextSibling){
                        $('<span style="color:red;">Got you!</span>').insertAfter(buf);
                        buf.data = '';
                    }
                    else{
                        buf = cn[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(sel.focusNode.previousSibling){
                let cn = sel.focusNode.parentElement.childNodes;
                for(i in cn){
                    if(buf){
                        $('<span style="color:red;">Got you!</span>').insertAfter(cn[i]);
                        cn[i].data = '';
                        buf = false;
                    }
                    else if(cn[i] == sel.focusNode.previousSibling){
                        buf = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } 
        else el.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Got you!</span>';
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example, click the text to replace:</p>

<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:4px;">You can't get me <strong id="item1">You can get me</strong> You can't get me
<div>You can't get me <strong id="item1">You can get me</strong> You can't get me</div></div>
```